# Uninstalling inbuilt call recorder

Tags: root-access, call-recording

I have iBall Andi 3.5 KKe winner, Android 4.2.2. It records every call and there is a logo "REC" on calling screen, showing recording time. There is no option of turning call recording off. In apps there is nothing like "auto call recording". I have rooted my phone. How to remove/uninstall auto call recording?

Comment: Have you gone into phone call settings in the phone dialer app?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily stop Automatic Call recoding by following steps:

- Go To Phone Dialer
- Press Option Button { At Left side of your home(middle) button}
- Go to Settings
- Go to Other Settings
- Turn Off Auto Recording

Thats It :)

Note: This option may not apply to all phones.

Answer (score 0):

Install an app that can handle uninstalling with root privileges for instance SD Maid, Titanium Backup, Rom Toolbox... When you enter any of these apps you can find something like an app manager and find Call app you want to uninstall. I highly recommend you backup the app before uninstalling just in case and then uninstall it. Also download a replacement app for calling. Contacts+ has a phone dial but chose what you like.

Answer (score 0):

As the app is System app, you can't uninstall the app without root privileges, Once you done with root you can uninstall system app using super user app that will create when phone get rooted.

For rooting your phone :

1) Farmaroot app

2) If incase above app not work,you can use Root Genius Software for PC.

- Install Root Genius on PC and Run it.
- Connect your Phone with PC using USB Debugging.
- In root genius Press Root, It will take some time to root your phone, and when it get completed you will see " Kinguser app" on your phone .
- Start Kinguser , GO to- -> King tool tab - -> Uninstall app you can uninstall from there.

Even if you cant uninstall the app from kinguser than there is one other app in play store.

- Link2SD

It will surely uninstall your Phone apk, but before you have to back up that app.